# Android Wear RoundedDrawable widget not found

Tags: android-studio, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I want to use RoundedDrawable widget, but it is not visible. This is my gradle dependency :

```
implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.2.0-alpha09'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.8.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.8.1'
implementation "androidx.wear:wear-input:1.1.0-alpha02"
```